# Constructing a valarray using raw data

Tags: c++, c++11, wrapper, object-construction, valarray

It seems I might be using `std::valarray<_Tp>`s for some computational work (suppose `_Tp` is `uint64_t`). Unfortunately, the following hold:

- my code receives raw arrays - `uint64_t*`s and a length value -
- I can't change signatures/APIs. They're `__restrict__`ed though.
- std::valarray's constructor which takes a `_Tp*` and a length copies the entire array.
- There do not seem to be methods for setting `std::valarray`'s internal data; it's even private so you can't access it in a subclass.

So how do I break this Gordian knot and construct a valarray without copying my data?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that. What `valarray` functionality do you need? You might be better off implementing that functionality for your raw array.

Comment: @Praetorian: I've [been told](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29807944/1593077) that valarray is a decent choice for performing bitwise operations on packed sequences of bits.

Comment: Are you using MSVC (I think they're the ones that allow the `__restrict__` extension)? If so, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6850807/241631), in particular, the second answer and Howard Hinnant's comment under the accepted answer. Have you inspected the assembly from an optimized build with a plain `for` loop bit ANDing one element at a time? It's possible the auto vectorizer will be able to transform that into SIMD instructions.

Comment: Seems I was remembering wrong, that's a gcc/clang extension. [clang3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/704455603de3ae52) seems willing to use SIMD if you write a plain `for` loop. I couldn't manage to get gcc to make use of the xmm registers, but you might have better luck with additional optimization flags/pragmas.

Comment: @Praetorian: Your comments belong more to the question I linked to than here... at any rate, I'm using gcc/Linux for now.